# Taking a Random Sample From Each Group in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, random

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to take a random sample of 100 records for each group in a table in Big Query.

For example, I have a table where column A is a unique recordID, and column B is the groupID to which the record belongs. For every distinct groupID, I would like to take a random sample of 100 recordIDs. Is there a simple way to complete this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like below should work

```
SELECT recordID, groupID
FROM (
  SELECT 
    recordID, groupID, 
    RAND() AS rnd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY groupID ORDER BY rnd) AS pos
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE pos <= 100
ORDER BY groupID, recordID
```

Also check RAND() [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#mathfunctions) if you want to improve randomness

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thanks much!

Comment: You don't really need final ORDER BY groupID, recordID

Comment: that's right! having order by in outter select in production can end up with resources exceeded issue. still usefull for simple testing

Comment: Did so! Thank you for the best practices tip

Comment: How are you able to reference the 'rnd' in the OVER()?

Comment: @PR102012 - This answer was given in 2016!!! and is/was for BigQuery Legacy SQL where you are able to reference column alias within the same statement. Obviously thois is not a case for Standard SQL

Comment: Are you aware of any solutions using Standard SQL?

Comment: @jalind - sure. feel free to post your specific question with all related details and I will be happy to answer

Comment: Unrecognized name: rnd

Comment: @s2t2 - see above comments! this answer was given in the era of BigQuery Legacy SQL - you can assure this by following link in the answer. Meantime just replace `rnd` with `rand()` and it will work with BigQuery Standard SQL :o)

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar need, namely cluster sampling, over 400M and more columns but hit `Exceeded resources...` error when using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

If you don't need `RAND()` because your data is unordered anyway, this performs quite well (<30s in my case):

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x LIMIT 100) 
FROM yourtable x 
GROUP BY groupId
```

You can:

- decorate with `UNNEST()` if front-end cannot render nested records
- add `ORDER BY groupId` to find/confirm patterns more quickly